# How to make closing of all columns in group possible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

So in agGrid I have columns grouped like this:

```js
public columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: '',
      children: [
        { field: 'field1', },
        { field: 'field2' },
        {
          field: 'field3',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      headerName: 'second_group',
      children: [
         { field: 'field4' }, 
         { field: 'field5', columnGroupShow: 'open' }
       ],
    },
  ];
```

This adds little arrow icon that makes it possible to toggle visibility of field5. Hovewer if I add `columnGroupShow: open` property to field4 there will be no expand/collapse button anymore. I would like to be able to hide all columns in `second_group` the same way it already works for mixed visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If we set the `columnGroupShow` to `show` for both the columns, there is not need to show the icon, as all the children will be shown by default.

> So the logic is atleast one child must have `columnGroupShow` set to `closed` for the expand/collapse icon to be shown! also not that if all columns have `closed` set then no icon will be shown since, there is no way to open icon!

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FMl7VaoYzP4g79a2?open=main.ts)

Comment: Well, that’s a shame and not the best conception in my opinion. Thank you for your answer!